# npm browserify version of jquery-select2 version 4.x

Tags: browserify, jquery-select2-4

I was wondering if :

1. There is a browserif'ied version of jquery-select2 4.x plugin available via npm?
2. If not, what do I need to do in order to get jquery-select2 4.x to work with my npm/browserify based project?

I was looking at the source on github and it seems like there is a require/almond.js version available. Can the same version be used with browserify without any changes?

I'm slightly confused as to what exactly am I required to do if I want to use jquery-select2 plugin with my project that uses npm and browserify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an [issue in select2-4.0.0](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/3288) when used in node/browserify environment. Until this issue is resolved you can depend on the [issue creator's fork](https://github.com/leftmostcat/select2) where it seems solved by pulling in `{"select2": "leftmostcat/select2"}` (instead of `select2/select2`) as dependency from within your `package.json`.

Comment: As of 2015-06-03 this is still an issue as the linked to fork is still being reviewed. See https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/3288#issuecomment-108596967

Answer (score 2):

As of today, you can simply load the latest version of Select2 at https://www.npmjs.com/package/select2.

Just install it by using `npm install select2`

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too. I solved that by adding the plugin with a script-tag to the page.

There ist no npm module for that plugin. There is only ember-select-2, a wrapper for jQuery select 2, but i don't know, if it ist the same. Just try it. But my above solution schuld work anyway.